# Add custom WebPartZone to existing page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, web-part-zone

I'm trying to add WebPartZone to existing page. I'm working with Sharepoint Designer (Site Actions -> Edit in SPD). I see a lot of ASP markup, but when Itry to add something like

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="TestZone1" ID="TestZone1">
<ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

There is an error: This Web Part Zone contains invalid non-Web Part content. Use code view to correct the content, or click to insert Web Part.

How can I fix it? Or maybe there is another way to add WebPArtZones to existing page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried adding your code to an aspx page and its working. Please to the following points from Microsoft.

Possible reasons include the following:

1. A Web Part may be restricted to a specific zone on the Web Part Page by the Web Part developer or Web Part Page author, or you are not allowed to modify the Web Part zone.
2. There are no zones on the Web Part Page.
3. You do not have the appropriate permission to update the Web Part Page or modify zones on the Web Part Page.
4. You receive a “missing assembly” message. Web Part developers can display a custom message when the Web Part assembly is not found. This can occur when the Web Part assembly file is not available, or when there is a version mismatch between the Web Part on your Web Part Page and the Web Part stored in the Web Part gallery.
5. There is a problem with the Web Part file (.dwp). The file may not have well-formed XML, or the Web Part XML schema may be invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I try to add zone to the homepage.

Comment: Pls check the id or try with a different id. It must be because of dulpicate ids on the page.
Also click No when Sharepoint alert you to remove unsafe content from the page.